# Что установить для работы с xml в phpStorm?

Tags: xml, phpstorm, плагин

Работаю с `phpStorm` уже давно и он полностью меня удовлетворял аж до того когда пришлось работать с `xml` .

Есть ли какой нибудь плагин для комфортной работы с `xml` ? 
**Кто чем пользуется ?**

Comment: а что не устраивает в стандартной ассоцииации xml phpStorm ?

Comment: @BroouzerKing, дело в том, что у меня даже нет (в phpStrom) когда я выбираю new, файла с расширением xml. Приходится после каждого названия дописывать .xm

Comment: Ну тип файла можно создать самому
new->edit file template и создать xml и стандартный шаблон к нем у а ассоциацию , потсветки синтаксиса и тд  настраиваются в  настройках, там же при необходимости можно догрузить нехватающий модуль

Comment: @BroouzerKing, спасибо )

Comment: 2016 год, забыть про XML и использовать уже JSON :)

Answer (score 2):

Если для работы со структурой, то есть плагин -

https://github.com/syllant/idea-plugin-xstructure

Но вроде встроенных возможностей хватает вполне.